# How to extend live persistence partition Kali linux USB?

Tags: kali-linux

I have Kali Linux Live persistence on USB, unfortunately I have ran out of space because I never created the partition big enough. Is there any way to extend the partition without deleting all of my configurations?

I heard GParted is good for this but I cannot install it.

I am new to Kali and I am a student studying Cyber Security, so I do not know a lot about it.

Comment: You cannot extend a partition that is being used. So either boot live-only or boot from another *live* linux system (many of them come with gparted pre-installed), and use gparted to increase the size of the partition for persistence (if there is drive space for it). But be aware that editing partitions is risky, and if you fail, your configurations will probably be lost. An alternative is to backup the content of the partition for persistence (for example with `rsync` or `tar`),

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize GParted was already installed. I am looking at it now and I have 33gb on an unallocated space. I can always back up my configurations but if not then that's alright I can always work it out again. Could you tell me how I would I go about trying to resize through GParted?

Comment: Try according to [this link](https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/GrowIt.pdf)